# customize time_zone_select rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I am using time_zone_select to list all the time zones in my select box. by default it displays list as follows :

```
(GMT-11:00) American Samoa
(GMT-11:00) International Date Line West
(GMT-11:00) Midway Island
.
.
.
etc.
```

But, I wanted it to display as follows :

```
American Samoa (GMT-11:00)
Alaska (GMT-09:00)
```

That is I want city name first and sorted by name

I managed to sort it , but coud not change the sequence

```
= f.time_zone_select( "user", "time_zone", ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort_by{|e| e.name}, model: ActiveSupport::TimeZone)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `select` instead of `time_zone_select`

```
= f.select( "user", "time_zone", ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort_by(&:name).map{|e| "#{e.name}(GMT#{e.formatted_offset})"})
```

Comment: Note you may want to use ```e.now.formatted_offset``` to avoid inconsistencies with Daylight Savings Time (Dublin and London can show different offsets..)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-to_s)

this should work for you

```
<%= f.select("user", "time_zone", ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort_by(&:name).map{|m|["#{m.name} (GMT#{m.formatted_offset})"]}, model: ActiveSupport::TimeZone) %>
# this comment is to avoid stack-overflow horizontal slider overlap for single line codes. ;p
```

Comment: Thank you @sat's :)